# Turn on request forgery protection with or witout Rails's protect_from_forgery?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, csrf

I building a REST API based on Rails 4.

To prevent from cross-site request forgery attacks, I added a CSRF token inside a custom HTTP header that is needed to perform requests such as POST, DELETE, etc.

I know Rails 4 also provides a `protect_from_forgery` method with a special option for APIs: `with: :null_session`.

So I think that, given it's a *best practice*, this new Rails method should be present at the top of my `ApplicationController`.

But in the same time, I'm also wondering why I should add it... if it is not necessary. Because as I said, my requiring a CSRF token inside a custom HTTP header.

Could you give me the benefits of adding this Rails feature? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look into the [Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html). It explains it pretty well.

Comment: Thanks. I already read it, but I'm don't know how to interpret the line "Provides an empty session during request but doesn't reset it completely. Used as default if `:with` option is not specified.". I could go inside Rails's code but if you already know the difference, I would be happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`protect_form_forgery` just adds a before action to the controller which checks if the `authenticity_token` is valid.

The `:with` parameter specifies how the controller should behave if the token is invalid.

- `with: :exception`: raises an exception in the controller which can by catched.
- `with: :null_session`: resets the session itself. This means the complete session will be deleted. In other words the session cookie will be reset. For example an `user_id` stored in the session won't be available anymore (`puts session[:user_id] # => nil`). So you always have to provide a token or any other authentication, which is perfectly fine for an API.

You can also remove `protect_from_forgery` if you don't use `session`.